# Data Stored in Redis cache is not found

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-redis-cache

We have used redis cache in web api project to add information on to the cache.

The same redis cache connection string we are using in Azure web Job to take the cached data stored in web api project.But we are not getting the cached data in Azure web Job as it is returning null data for that region.

```
 <add key="RedisCacheStorageHours" value="8" />
```

Please Help.

Comment: you'll need to add some code

Comment: Your description lacks few details, such as some necessary code, What the `RedisCacheStorageHours` is, etc. Please post more information to help analyzing your issue.

Comment: @ Peter Pan , RedisCacheStorageHours is set to 8 hours as mentioned in the question. Along with that we have added same redis cache connection string to retrive region or data from the cache. Please let me know anything more required.

Comment: Any process now?

Answer (score 0):

As I have tested, when you fail to connect to the Redis Cache, it doesn't give any error prompt, and its vault is null.

Here is an article about [Use Azure Cache for Redis with a .NET application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache).
The detailed steps are as below:

1.Set connectionstring in `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="CacheConnection" value="<cache-name>.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=<access-key>"/>
</appSettings>
```

2.Install [StackExchange.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/) package.

3.Use the following code to retrieve cache data.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDatabase cache = lazyConnection.Value.GetDatabase();
    string cacheCommand = "GET Message";
    Console.WriteLine("\nCache command  : " + cacheCommand + " or StringGet()");
    Console.WriteLine("Cache response : " + cache.StringGet("Message").ToString());
    lazyConnection.Value.Dispose();
 }
```

After testing fine on local, you could publish the console app as azure webjobs and it will take the cached data as you want.